# How to execute codeigniter controller from batch file

Tags: php, codeigniter, batch-file

i want to schedule a task to run at certain time in php and i am using codeigniter framework .
so want to write a batch file to execute the given function in a  given controller. Ihave written a batch file for simple php file its working correctly but giving an error while writing for the codeigniter.

below is my batch file for codeigniter

C:\xampp\php\php.exe -f C:\xampp\htdocs\DatabaseServices\index.php\controller_name\FUNCTION_NAME
it is giving an error 'unable to load the file'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See the [Codeigniter Documentation on the CLI interface](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/cli.html).

> Now normally you would visit the your site using a URL similar to this: example.com/index.php/tools/message
>
> Instead, we are going to open Terminal in Mac/Lunix or go to Run > "cmd" in Windows and navigate to our CodeIgniter project:

```
$ cd /path/to/project;
$ php index.php tools message
```

Make sure you are sending the right arguments for your controllers.

In your case:

```
cd C:\xampp\htdocs\DatabaseServices
C:\xampp\php\php.exe index.php controller_name FUNCTION_NAME
```

Comment: What about it is not working? That's just not enough for me to help you.

Comment: do you have the same problem or another problem ?

Comment: the link is outdated, please use https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/cli.html